# Android Studio - run greyed out

Tags: android-studio

When I opened various projects, the Run, Debug, and Run with Coverage are greyed out.  I tried doing Run -> Edit configurations.  There was only  and no other options with that method. My Genymotion emulator didn't work either.  It didn't do anything.   I don't know if that helps.   I did restart my computer and Android Studio.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Please share a screenshot, it would be easier to help.